# assigns(:user) returning nil rather than user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The following test that I have written is:

```
  test "valid signup information with account activation" do
    get root_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post_via_redirect users_path, user: { user_name: "Example1234",
                                            email: "user1234@example.com",
                                            password: "password",
                                            password_confirmation: "password"}
    end
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    user = assigns(:user)
    assert_not user.activated?
    #Try to log in before activation.
    log_in_as(user)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    #Invalid activation token
    get edit_account_activation_path("invalidtoken", email: user.email)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    #Valid token, wrong email
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: "wrongemail")
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    #Valid activation token
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: user.email)
    assert user.reload.activated?
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'recipes/index'
    assert is_logged_in?
  end
```

And I get the following error:

```
ERROR["test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation", UsersSignupTest, 1.4278587700100616]
 test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation#UsersSignupTest (1.43s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `activated?' for nil:NilClass
            test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:30:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
```

Note that line 30 is the first assert_not user.activated?

It appears that the assigns(:user) is not getting the actual user and I can't seem to figure out why.

I'm following Hartl's tutorial and this is the test in [Chapter 10](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset) . Any ideas why the user is not returning

**EDIT:**

Here is my controller code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  .....

   def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        @user.send_activation_email
        format.html { redirect_to root_url notice: 'Please check your email to activate.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors }
      end
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Here is my Account Activations Controller.

```
class AccountActivationsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.activate
      log_in user
      flash[:success] = "Account activated! Welcome!."
      redirect_to recipes_url
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link."
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show your controller code?

Comment: @AnthonyE Edited above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK! So I figured this one out eventually.

I'm still not sure why but I changed the code in the test from: post_via_redirect to just a post and it worked properly.

I did this mostly because I noticed in the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) for assigns(:) that it comes after a post rather than a post_via_redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is not in your user controller, but in your account_activation controller:

```
class AccountActivationsController < ApplicationController

 def edit
     user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
   if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation,params[:id])
  user.activate....
```

**Update** Error may be in the test

From the tutorial

```
test "valid signup information with account activation" do
get signup_path #You have get root_path here!!!
assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
  post users_path, user: { name:  "Example User",
                           email: "user@example.com",
                           password:              "password",
                           password_confirmation: "password" }
end
```

The signup_path is where the methods are that contain user.activated?

Comment: I updated my original post to include that code. What do you think is the error in the AccountActivationsController?

Comment: @blueduckyy Sorry, the code in that controller appears correct. I believe the error is stating that you don't have user.activated? somewhere in your application. I'm assuming this is the test from listing 10.31. Right above it in listing 10.30, he modifies the create method to include if user.activated? Could you have overlooked that?

Comment: I do have the if user.activated? in the create method from 10.30. I'm curious, why do you think that I don't have user.activated? somewhere in my application? The only stack trace that is mentioned is in the test file, so I assume it was the user.activated? in the test file that was failing.

Comment: @blueduckyy The tests are written to help correct your code. The test shows you what is missing, you fix it, run test again, test is green...everything is great. I did this tutorial not too long ago, and had many of the same problems, maybe not this exact problem, can't remember, but I had problems. I could suggest one more thing: Try activating a new user in the browser and see if there is an error there. It may be helpful.

Comment: @blueduckyy Please see updated answer, hopefully it is correct

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have the root_path there because thats where my sign up is. If I uncomment the rest of the code it seems to work fine. It's just when I added the account_activation piece that it started to fail.